# How to close popups in another html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Radio on my website that is openned in a popup window, but i create a page that have a song, so i want to close the popup when i access this page.

The website link is this http://www.saproject.com.br/

When you click in the radio link in the right of the site, the music starts, but when u click in the black banner the popup needs to close.

i tried to use window.opener.close(), but dont works.

the radio is just a link that open a popup;

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.close();
```

instead of

```
window.opener.close();
```

**Note**: You will be only able to close the window if you opened it using javascript.

And `window.opener.close()` closes the parent window, not the popup.

Comment: but i need to close the popup using by another page.

Comment: so while opening the window assign it to a variable.var win = window.open(......);. And later, when clicked on the banner, win.close();

Answer (score 0):

Try saving a pointer to the window you just opened , and then use the pointer to close it,
For Example:

```
var myWindow = window.open('myWindow',...);
```

and then use the pointer:

```
if (myWindow && !myWindow.closed) {
    myWindow.close();
}
```